# How do I count unique items in field in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My Table: table1

```
ID  Name  Family
1   A     AA
2   B     BB
3   A     AB
4   D     DD
5   E     EE
6   A     AC
```

SQL command on Access:

```
select count(*) from table1
```

***Output:***  ------------> True
6 row(s)

I tried to count unique names:

**Expected output:** 4 row(s)

```
select count(distinct Name) from table1
```

***Output on Access:***  ------------> Error

What changes do I need to make to my query?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Count(*) AS N
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1) AS T;
```

Read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20120805022223/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I think even this SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1);  will do.

Comment: Yeah may be, I'm not sure but having an alias is always better so that alias can be used for fetching other columns but in this particular case you are right if "Access supports that syntax" of course.

Comment: We're sorry, but we can't find the page you're looking for.  Link is dead

Comment: @SubirKumarSao This worked for me. Simple and sweet.

Answer (score 11):

Access-Engine does not support

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT....) FROM ...
```

You have to do it like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1)
```

Its a little workaround... you're counting a DISTINCT selection.

Answer (score 4):

A quick trick to use for me is using the find duplicates query SQL and changing 1 to 0 in Having expression. Like this:

```
SELECT COUNT([UniqueField]) AS DistinctCNT FROM
(
  SELECT First([FieldName]) AS [UniqueField]
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY [FieldName]
  HAVING (((Count([FieldName]))>0))
);
```

Hope this helps, not the best way I am sure, and Access should have had this built in.