# Count unique values grouped by name in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

The answer to exercise #3 at [tech on the net](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php) is exactly what I need.  However through my own experience and [Jensen's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query) I've found that it doesn't work.

I have data that looks like this:

```
my_table:
: Customer : Contract : Product : Date    :
: John     : 123      : Plate   : 12/5/13 :
: John     : 123      : Spork   : 12/5/13 :
: Jane     : 567      : Bowl    : 9/9/13  :
: Jane     : 789      : Plate   : 9/9/13  :
: Jane     : 789      : Spork   : 9/9/13  :
: Bob      : 234      : Plate   : 8/7/13  :
: John     : 345      : Plate   : 4/9/13  :
: John     : 345      : Sponge  : 4/9/13  :
```

What I want is to get the number of unique contracts for each customer.

```
my_query
: Customer : Number of Contracts :
: Jane     : 2                   :
: John     : 2                   :
: Bob      : 1                   :
```

If I wanted just the contracts from June 2013 to June 2014, (past year), then I would get:

```
my_query
: Customer : Number of Contracts :
: Jane     : 2                   :
: Bob      : 1                   :
: John     : 1                   :
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to get the distinct customer/contract combinations then you can do a group by on the subquery to get the counts.

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) AS contract_count
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Customer, Contract
    FROM my_table) contract_data
GROUP BY Customer
```

If you want to do a date filter, you would filter in the subquery.

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) AS contract_count
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Customer, Contract
    FROM my_table
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #6/1/2013# AND #6/1/2014#) contract_data
GROUP BY Customer
```