# can anyone figure out how to get a query to return a count of distinct records?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a simple query:

[image]

If these are the query results :

[image]

Record Count =16.  How can I find the count of “distinct” MemberIDs?  Should be 7.

This is the SQL:

SELECT tblAttendanceHistory.ActivityDate, tblAttendanceHistory.MemberID, tblAttendanceHistory.Attended
FROM tblAttendanceHistory
GROUP BY tblAttendanceHistory.ActivityDate, tblAttendanceHistory.MemberID, tblAttendanceHistory.Attended
HAVING (((tblAttendanceHistory.ActivityDate)Date()-30) AND ((tblAttendanceHistory.Attended)=True))
ORDER BY tblAttendanceHistory.MemberID;

Where would your suggestion fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count distinct ...)`:

```
select count(distinct memberId) memberCount
from mytable
```

Comment: so how does this fit in the SQL?

Comment: OK...I think you mean :   SELECT Count(DISTINCT QAttendedLast30days.MemberID) AS CountOfMemberID
FROM QAttendedLast30days;                                                 
but I get "Syntax Error (missing operator in query expression 'Count(DISTINCT QAttendedLast30days.MemberID)'

Comment: Your SQL looks OK. To help debug this, please create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post the link.

Comment: SUCCESS....so the answer was found at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query   .  The trick was the format as indicated in the post.