# Count clause in MS Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have an excel spreadsheet with:

```
PatientID, PatientName, DateofService
```

I want to find out, how many times one patient has visited the doctor and I am trying to import the spreadsheet in MS Access(2010) and use SQL query but I am having errors every time using the `COUNT` clause. Please help with the SQL query in "ACCESS" to count the each patients'visit(s).

Comment: What is the query? What is the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count unique items in field in Access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query)

Answer (score 1):

A query like the following should work for you (Put this in the SQL editor then you can toggle back to the usual query builder view):

```
SELECT patientNAme, count(DateOFService) as visits FROM <yourTableName> GROUP BY patientName
```

That will group by PatientName then count the number of times they have visited the doctor. If you want to limit this to a single patient then you can use a WHERE Statement:

```
SELECT patientNAme, count(DateOFService) as visits FROM <yourTableName> WHERE patientID = <yourpatientID> GROUP BY patientName
```