# Count(Distinct FieldName) in access query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to write a query in Ms access 2010 but it is not allowing Count(Distinct OrderID) syntax in there which I am easily able to write in oracle.

```
Select BrandID, Count(Distinct OrderID), Count(Distinct ModelID)
 From ordertable
   Where Trunc(Pur_Date) Between '01-Feb-2015' And '09-Feb-2015'
Group By BrandID
Order by BrandID
```

Table structure:

```
 OrderID  BrandID  ModelID
   1        abc      a
   1        abc      b
   1        abc      c
   2        def      f
   3        ghi      a
   3        ghi      c
   4        abc      g
   4        abc      b
```

Please help in achieving this.

Comment: Yes I tried the same but it only works or I was not able to figure a way out of when I want to do this:-

       Select Count(Distinct OrderID)
       From ordertable
       Where Trunc(Pur_Date) Between '01-Feb-2015' And '09-Feb-2015'

Only one field but I want to group by then based on the BrandID show the unique counts.

Please help.

Comment: @SankarRaj That gives OrderID count as 5 for Brand "abc" where I want it to be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [How do I count unique items in field in Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query) Access does not have a `COUNT DISTINCT` operator. The workaround is to `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subquery and count the results. Furthermore, since you are counting two independent columns, you must count from two *separate* subqueries - one for each column. The easiest way to do this is to use a `UNION` with a 0 placeholder, then sum the results:

```
select BrandID, sum(orders), sum(models)
from (
    select BrandID, count(OrderID) orders, 0 models
    from (
        select distinct BrandID, OrderID
        from ordertable
        where Trunc(Pur_Date) between '01-Feb-2015' and '09-Feb-2015'
    ) x1
    group by BrandID
    union all
    select BrandID, 0 orders, count(ModelID) models
    from (
        select distinct BrandID, ModelID
        from ordertable
        where Trunc(Pur_Date) between '01-Feb-2015' and '09-Feb-2015'
    ) x2
    group by BrandID
) o
group by BrandID
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ce7c/3) of this query running in SQL Server.

Comment: Seems that it will help :)

Will check and confirm

Comment: Thanks @Ic this works like charm :) , just another query that if I got two three more fields to add then I have to create more x3 , x4 sub queries right ?

Comment: @SK glad it worked. And yes if you have more fields just add more subqueries to the union

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help..

```
 SELECT d.BrandID, Count(d.OrderID), Count(d.ModelID)
FROM (select distinct BrandID, OrderID,ModelID from ordertable
      Where Trunc(Pur_Date) Between '01-Feb-2015' And '09-Feb-2015') as d 
Group By d.BrandID
Order by d.BrandID
```

[image: result]

Comment: That gives OrderID count as 5 for Brand "abc" where I want it to be 2

Comment: This is not running.

Comment: why there's two `from` ?

Comment: @SK hope you get the result now

Comment: Hello Sachu this also works but it doesn't give unique count for both of the fields.