# Counting Distinct Items based on Conditional Statments

Tags: sql, ms-access

Okay, I'm pretty sure this has been answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. I also apologizes if I don't follow proper (read as helpful) etiquette on asking this question. My assumption is that the answer is simple, but my SQL is virtually non-existant and I am at my wits end.

I have two tables in MS Access. I am having trouble getting the desired count with a **SELECT DISTINCT** query

**Table1: **Sales Products - Each product that we have sold

| Job Number | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Window |
| 0001 | Window |
| 0001 | Door |
| 0002 | Window |
| 0002 | Roof |
| 0002 | Door |
| 0003 | Siding |

**Table 2: **Products - A List of all Products that we sell

| Product | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Window | 1 |
| Door | 2 |
| Siding | 3 |
| Roof | 4 |

**My desired goal: **A Query that lists how many jobs included a particular product (example: Window) despite how many of that product they would have ordered. Example Below:

| Product | Job Count |
| --- | --- |
| Window | 2 |
| Door | 2 |
| Siding | 1 |
| Roof | 1 |

I can just feel that I'm missing something simple, but is it a conditional clause with the SELECT DISTINCT? or something else entirely?

I've tried every SELECT DISTINCT forum posting solution I can think of but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count(Distinct FieldName) in access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308755/countdistinct-fieldname-in-access-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product, COUNT(DISTINCT job) as job_count   
FROM sales_product  
GROUP BY product
```

This will count the distinct number of jobs associated with each product.
If your sales_product table uses a product_id instead of the product name, you will need a join in your query as follows:

```
SELECT p.product, COUNT(DISTINCT job) as job_count  
FROM sales_product sp  
INNER JOIN product p on sp.product_id = p.id  
GROUP BY p.product
```

**Note**: Any products without any associated jobs will be omitted from the results. If you want to include products with a job_count of zero, you would want to do something similar but placing the count within a subquery.