# SQL Syntax error(missing operator)

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have this query :

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Class)
    from student ;
```

I am getting :

> syntax error(missing operator) in this query.

Comment: MySql and ms-access are two very different systems. Which one are you using really?

Comment: Sounds like ms-access : see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query

Comment: I have found out the reason. This problem is arising because I am using MS-Access.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably after this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As ClassCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Class FROM student);
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As ClassCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Class FROM student) AS T;
```