# Distinct Count with Group By in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I am working in a table in SQL and attempting to get the distinct counts of transaction numbers for each retailer during certain days in my dataset. Right now this is what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT (*), pos_table.Retailer

FROM pos_table

WHERE Month(Timestamp) = 3 AND Day(Timestamp) = 3 OR Day(Timestamp) = 4

Group By Retailer
```

This gives me the counts for each retailer but when I add "COUNT (DISTINCT pos_table.Transaction) in place of COUNT (*) it does not run.

Comment: What do you mean `it does not run`?

Comment: I am using Access and it gives me "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT (DISTINCT pos_table.Transaction)'"

Comment: MS Access doesn't support count(distinct ...).. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access didn't support `count(distinct [colunm])` you can try to write a subquery to make it.

```
select COUNT(t1.Transaction),t1.Retailer
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Transaction,t1.Retailer
    FROM pos_table AS t1
    WHERE Month(t1.Timestamp) = 3 AND Day(t1.Timestamp) = 3 OR Day(t1.Timestamp) = 4
) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.Retailer
```

Comment: When I do that it prompts me for the transaction number and retailer

Comment: @MichaelRyan Try to use Ailsa name on table and make sure the column name is correct.

Comment: It still prompts me for the Transaction number, not sure where since it should only be outputting that info

Comment: Are you sure `Transaction` in your table or could you show use your table info