# Count users and groups totals in one query

Tags: ms-access

I am super new to access and having difficulty with a query. My table (tblpacks) is the following:

```
 id user_id group_id quota_id
 1    1        1       1
 2    1        2       1
 3    2        1       1
 4    3        1       1
```

Ideally, what I now is to get hte number of unique users and groups for quota_id=1

The result will be:

```
       total_users = 3
       total_groups = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanted to count one field, there would by a simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11880199/6777839), but since you want to count 2 separate fields, you in fact need at least 2 separate queries.

My answer is to use a UNION query as the source for counting. This UNION query returns the distinct `user_id` values (with `Null` as `group_id`) and the distinct `group_id` values (with `Null` as `user_id`). I omitted the DISTINCT keyword, because UNION (without ALL) does a DISTINCT query automatically. As the datatypes where not recognized correctly when using a constant `Null` field in the first SELECT statement of the UNION query, I added a third SELECT statement as the first one, which selects both fields from the table but returns no records:

```sql
SELECT Count(user_id) AS total_users, Count(group_id) AS total_groups
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, group_id FROM tblpacks WHERE Yes=No
  UNION
  SELECT user_id, Null FROM tblpacks WHERE quota_id=1
  UNION
  SELECT Null, group_id FROM tblpacks WHERE quota_id=1
) AS qsub;
```

Comment: Just rewrote it as  null as group_id / null as client_id to avoid the first Yes=No query and it yields the same result and not bad speed wise too. Thanks Kais

Comment: Wellcome, and good to know that counting works without the Yes=No query. I tested the UNION query alone and did not see the `group_id` values, thats why I added that auxiliary query. :-)