# How do i convert this sql CODE so that MS Access understands it?

Tags: sql, ms-access, view

I've got a homework that includes SQL with MS Access I've been trying hard to figure it out but could'nt.. Im just getting an error message.. My code is for a view..

This is the code:

```
(SELECT Rum, COUNT(DISTINCT(Larare)) AS antal FROM Kurstillfalle
GROUP BY Rum)
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access does not support COUNT(DISTINCT columnname) but you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  t.Rum, 
  COUNT(t.Larare)) AS antal 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Rum, Larare FROM Kurstillfalle) AS t 
GROUP BY t.Rum
```

Comment: Thanks alot, worked!!

Can you see anything wrong with the code below? I'm not getting any result in the column student? It should show me the students from any date in year 2010?


SELECT DISTINCT student
FROM Deltagande
WHERE startdatum LIKE '2010%'

Comment: replace `%` with `*`

Comment: Is there any problem with using intersect in access? Or is the trouble somewhere else?

Comment: There is no intersect in access as far as I know.

Comment: SELECT L.personnummer, P.namn, L.tjänsterum, P.telefon 
FROM Person P, Lärare L, Kurstillfälle KT, Rum R
WHERE P.personnummer = L.personnummer 
AND L.personnummer = KT.lärare
AND KT.rum = R.id
AND R.namn = 'Jupiter' 
INTERSECT
SELECT L.personnummer, P.namn, L.tjänsterum, P.telefon 
FROM Person P, Lärare L, Kurstillfälle KT, Rum R
WHERE P.personnummer = L.personnummer 
AND L.personnummer = KT.lärare
AND KT.rum = R.id
AND R.namn = 'Sirius' 
--------------------------------------------> What's the problem here? I appreciate your help, thank's alot! =)

Comment: As I said if this is code for MS Access, INTERSECT is not supported.