# Count distinct values of a Column based on Distinct values of First Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am dealing with a huge volume of traffic data. I want to identify the vehicles which have changed their lanes, I'm Microsoft Access with VB.Net.

Traffic Data:

```
Vehicle_ID   Lane_ID   Frame_ID   Distance  
        1        2        12        100  
        1        2        13        103  
        1        2        14        105  
        2        1        16        130  
        2        1        17        135  
        2        2        18        136  
        3        1        19        140  
        3        2        20        141
```

I have tried to distinct the Vehicle_ID and then count(distinct Lane_ID).
I could list the distinct Vehicle_ID but the it counts the total Lane_ID instead of Distinct Lane_ID.

```
SELECT
    Distinct Vehicle_ID, count(Lane_ID)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Vehicle_ID
```

Shown Result:

```
Vehicle_ID  Lane Count  
       1    3  
       2    3  
       3    2
```

Correct  Result:

```
Vehicle_ID  Lane Count  
       1    1  
       2    2  
       3    2
```

Further to that i would like to get all Vehicle_ID who have changed their lane (all data including previous lane and new lane). Output result would be somehow like: Vehicle_ID   Lane_ID   Frame_ID   Distance
        2        1        17        135
        2        2        18        136
        3        1        19        140
        3        2        20        141

Comment: Further to that i would like to get all Vehicle_ID who have changed their lane (all data including previous lane and new lane). Output result would be somehow like: Vehicle_ID   Lane_ID   Frame_ID   Distance  
        2        1        17        135  
        2        2        18        136  
        3        1        19        140  
        3        2        20        141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  Table1.Vehicle_ID,
  LANE_COUNT
FROM Table1
JOIN (
   SELECT Vehicle_ID, COUNT(*) as LANE_COUNT FROM (
      SELECT distinct Vehicle_ID, Lane_ID FROM Table1
   ) dTable1 # distinct vehicle and land id
   GROUP BY Vehicle_ID # counting the distinct
) cTable1 ON cTable1.Vehicle_ID = Table1.Vehicle_ID # join the table with the counting
```

I think you should do one by one,

1. Distinct the vehicle id and land id
2. counting the distinct combination
3. and merge the result with the actual table.

Comment: Thanks Jacky. But it shows " Syntax error in FROM clause"

Answer (score 3):

Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT columnname)` so do this:

```
SELECT t.Vehicle_ID, COUNT(t.Lane_ID) AS [Lane Count]
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle_ID, Lane_ID FROM Table1
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Vehicle_ID
```

So

> to identify the vehicles which have changed their lanes

you need to add to the above query:

```
HAVING COUNT(t.Lane_ID) > 1
```

Comment: I see you frequent the `ms-access` tags and at times point out the dialect's limitation such as your first sentence which you also mentioned a [month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329044/1422451). I agree, so much so, I recently added a [suggestion](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) to the Access team the high time to upgrade its SQL dialect to current standards. Please vote, comment, share!

Comment: I did not even remember that post! Your suggestion makes sense, upvoted.

Comment: Thanks Forpas...It is absolutely perfect for me.

Comment: If it worked, you may consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vehicles that have *changed* their lanes, then you can do:

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID,
       IIF(MIN(Lane_ID) = MAX(Lane_ID), 0, 1) as change_lane_flag
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Vehicle_ID;
```

I think this is as good as counting the number of distinct lanes, because you are not counting actual "lane changes".  So this would return "2" even though the vehicle changes lanes multiple times:

```
    2        1        16        130  
    2        1        17        135  
    2        2        18        136  
    2        1        16        140  
    2        1        17        145  
    2        2        18        146
```