# Why Select Distinct stored 'As T' and how to alias?

Tags: sql, ms-access

From this helpful response on another question on stackoverflow.com ([How do I count unique items in field in Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880199/how-do-i-count-unique-items-in-field-in-access-query#)), the answer contained:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS N
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1) AS T;
```

Why is the distinct selection aliased "As T" (i.e. not why the letter T, but why do this?)

If you had the case of:

```
SELECT Count(Long_Table_Name_Here.[Field1]) AS N
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Long_Table_Name_Here) AS T;
```

How could you also alias the long table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MS Access requires that every "object" referred to in the `FROM` clause has a name.  Tables have a default name -- which is their name.  (Actually, you can use either multi-part name or just the table name.)

As for your second query:

```
SELECT Count(Long_Table_Name_Here.[Field1]) AS N
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Long_Table_Name_Here) AS T;
```

This will result in a syntax error because `Long_Table_Name_Here` is not defined.  You need to use the table alias defined in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT Count(T.[Field1]) AS N
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Long_Table_Name_Here) AS T;
```